# PowerMock on Android Project

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

Hello all powermock users,

I am trying to write some Android testcases using Powermockito. I am using eclipse as my IDE and run the tests as **"Android JUnit tests"**

When I just Mockito v1.9.5 (along with the Dexmaker-1.1.jar & Dexmaker-mockito-1.1.jar) all my test pass. Some of the test have mocks and some don't.

When I add the powermock-mockito-1.5.6-full.jar to my libs folder and change my imports to

```
   import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;
```

Things start to break. (  I am just using mock() and when() calls )

Below is my testcase class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

@PrepareForTest({AuthSettings.class})

public class NetworkServicesImplTest extends ActivityTestCase{


 @Override

 protected void setUp() throws Exception  {

     super.setUp();

     System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getCacheDir().getPath()); 

     Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()); 
     obj = new MyObj();

 }

       private MyObject obj;

        public void testSimpleTest() {

               Response response = mock(Response.class);

               Data data = mock(Data.class);


                when(response.getString()).thenReturn("dummy");

                obj.setString(response);

               String str1 = obj.getString(dsContext, data);

               assertEquals("dummy",str1);

       }

       public void testGetDSClientExecutionContextURL() throws MalformedURLException {

               DSHttpResponse response;

               // Mock our class
               HttpRequestParameters mockHttpRequest = mock(HttpRequestParameters.class);

               final URL url = new URL("https://");

               try{
                     // PowerMock API                        
                       whenNew(HttpRequestParameters.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockHttpRequest);

                       response = network.get(dsContext, url);

               }catch(Exception ex){

                       response = null;

                       fail("should not have got an exception" + ex);

               }

               assertNotNull(response);

       }
```

This is the Exception on the first testcase:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: org/mockito/cglib/core/ReflectUtils

at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:167)

at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)

at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)

at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)

at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)

at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)

at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)

at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:70)

at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:85)

at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)

at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:111)

at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:60)

at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:143)

at com.citrix.work.network.impl.test.NetworkServicesImplTest.testSimpleTest(NetworkServicesImplTest.java:91)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)

at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)

at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)

at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)

at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)

at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1729)
```

and the subsequest testcase throws

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/internal/creation/jmock/ClassImposterizer$3
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:85)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:111)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:60)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:143)
at com.citrix.work.network.impl.test.NetworkServicesImplTest.testGetDSClientExecutionContextURL(NetworkServicesImplTest.java:107)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1729)
```

Does anyone here have successfully done Unit testing on an Android Project using PowerMockito ?

**But when I ran them from Command line setting the classpath, the tests ran.**
I ran the test using JUnit4 via the

```
java -cp . org.junit.runner.JUnitCore <testclass>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.